# VSTS: Built in variable for organization name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In many of the calls described in the Azure DevOps REST API documentation, I need to supply the name of the organization, e.g.:

`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8`

The project I can get from System.TeamProject. I would have expected something similar for organization name, something like:

System.TeamFoundationCollectionName

This does not seem to be available. I've even printed out all of my environment variables on the agent and don't see anything that fits the need exactly. Sure, I can parse it out of one of the other values, but this seems fragile since MS seems to like to change the format of URLs.

I also can't hard code the organization name because this release definition will live in multiple organizations and we don't want to have to manually update it for each. How are others solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `System.TeamFoundationServerUri` and `System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri` to build your API requests. They have the organization included in them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch

edit: `SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI/BUILD_PROJECTNAME/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8`

Comment: I've tried both with the API call posted above and get a 404 in both cases. It appears that I need the exact formatting as posted above.

Comment: I tested that example previously with no luck, but gave it another shot with your suggestion in case I had a typo. Same result as before (404).

Comment: `https://{organization}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Copied directly from my logs with org and project names omitted: `https://xxx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/yyy/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8`

Comment: Also verified the verb is post

Comment: The verb should be get

Comment: For a create, the verb is post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180684/discussion-between-calidus-and-fepiv).

Comment: Just to follow up, we debugged it in a chat and it turned out that my JSON was malformed. Once fixed, the suggested fix worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like currently there is no such variable for the `organization`, also, the variables return the old URL (`xxx.visualstudio.com`) and not the new URL (`dev.azure.com/xxx`) so if you use the `System.TeamFoundationCollectionName` the API should work without the `{organization}`:

`https://System.TeamFoundationCollectionName/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8`.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, do this:

```
# Where SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI=https://some_org_name.visualstudio.com/    
([System.Uri]$Env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI).Host.split('.')[-3] # returns 'some_org_name'
```

Now, just assign that to a variable and use it anywhere you like. "SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT" is the Project Name, so no need to do any parsing there.  It is already available.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is too fragile since MS doesn't guarantee that their URLs will always be formatted the same way. Using this method would have started failing just a couple weeks ago when they announced the URL format change/rename of VSTS to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but any of the answers given so far fail.  This is the only answer so far that is automated with today's current situation that actually works.  The so called "answer" that is approved doesn't work.